# How to solve PHPModules error in Grav while installing it for the first time?

Tags: php, grav

I am a first time user of Grav. 
1. I downloaded the 'Grav' core.
2. Unzipped it to the root directory of Apache webserver (using latest XAMPP), 
3. Modified the permissions to 777 in htdocs directory (using `chmod -R 777 .`) 
4. Launched the website.

I am getting the following error:

```
> [2019-05-13 08:17:09] grav.CRITICAL: Class
> 'Grav\Plugin\Problems\._PHPModules' not found - Trace: #0
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/user/plugins/problems/problems.php(128):
> Grav\Plugin\Problems\Base\ProblemChecker->check('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
> #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/user/plugins/problems/problems.php(47): Grav\Plugin\ProblemsPlugin->problemsFound() #2
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(212):
> Grav\Plugin\ProblemsPlugin->onFatalException(Object(RocketTheme\Toolbox\Event\Event),
> 'onFatalExceptio...',
> Object(RocketTheme\Toolbox\Event\EventDispatcher)) #3
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44):
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array,
> 'onFatalExceptio...', Object(RocketTheme\Toolbox\Event\Event)) #4
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/rockettheme/toolbox/Event/src/EventDispatcher.php(23):
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('onFatalExceptio...',
> Object(RocketTheme\Toolbox\Event\Event)) #5
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/system/src/Grav/Common/Grav.php(365):
> RocketTheme\Toolbox\Event\EventDispatcher->dispatch('onFatalExceptio...',
> Object(RocketTheme\Toolbox\Event\Event)) #6
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php(55):
> Grav\Common\Grav->fireEvent('onFatalExceptio...',
> Object(RocketTheme\Toolbox\Event\Event)) #7 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though, I didn't take time in solving this issue in my local machine, I found a workaround. I downloaded the desired grav skeleton zip file and uploaded the same in the hosting provider's File Manager. I then extracted it there and launched the website. Worked like a charm! Referred this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yyE-LaAa8Y